# Authenticating users in Spring MVC - several types of users (different classes)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, authentication

I'm developing a web application using the Spring MVC + Hibernate combo. I've come to a big "but..." tonight:

I have two different types of users, with quite a lot of different properties. That is, I want the app to be able to authenticate several types of user objects. A few days ago I thought this was not going to be a problem, and I wrote a `BaseUser` entity, and a `IUser` interface, so I've got:

```
RegularUser extends BaseUser implements IUser;

PremiumUser extends BaseUser implements IUser;
```

Now, several questions arise: I have this `interface UserService`:

```
public interface UserService {
    public boolean authenticateUser(IUser user);
}
```

Should I have as many implementations of this interface as IUser implementations?
When I want to authenticate a user, how can I tell regular users from premium users, prior to creating the user object to authenticate?

My goal is to have the application choose the right object to authenticate, given the fact that there cannot be two users with the same name accross all user implementations. I'm a bit confused.

Some extra information:

An example implementation of the `authenticate(IUser user)` method would be:

```
@Service("regularUserService")
public class RegularUserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
RegularUserDAOImpl userDAO;

@Transactional
public boolean authenticateUser(IUser user) {
    if (user == null || !(user instanceof RegularUser)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        String name = user.getName();
        String pass = user.getPassword();       
        RegularUser existingUser = userDAO.findByName(name);

        if (existingUser == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if (pass.equals(existingUser.getPassword())) {
                if (existingUser.getIsEnabled()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
...
}
```

If I've got an equivalent `PremiumUserServiceImpl` with the same authenticate() method, how would Spring know which one to proxy (i.e., which UserService implementation to choose)?

Thanks in advance,
Dan.

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using Spring Security to do this for you? It will literally take away all these problems. All you need to do is add a boolean field on your users called enabled and add a collection of role names. Have a look into authentication with Spring Security, its a really nice package

Answer (score 0):

> how can I tell regular users from premium users, prior to creating the
>   user object to authenticate?

ok, you have

```
@Service("regularUserService")
public class RegularUserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    .....
}
```

and another one like:

```
@Service("premiumUserService")
public class PremiumUserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    .....
}
```

OK, but Spring will found more than one implementation of `UserService`, use `@Primary` annotation to tell Spring which autowire candidate will preferred when more than one matching bean instance exists.
for example if you want to make `RegularUserService` as prior then add `@Primary` on it:

```
@Primary
@Service("regularUserService")
public class RegularUserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    .....
}
```

---

**See Also:**

- [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html)
- [@Named and @Inject](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was reading yesterday about `@Primay` and `@Named`, but I think that wouldn't solve the problem: Spring would just go for the implementation annotated with `@Primary`. Maybe my problem is not so clearly explained - I'm working now on a solution, I'll post it to make both question and answer clear if I find a clean solution.